# Form action loses post ID after validation error - CakePHP

Tags: php, html, forms, cakephp, validation

My edit action is working great if I don't have any validation errors.

When validation errors are found, the view is rendered again with the error messages, but the URL in the form tag's action looses the post id.

e.g.

Before validation errors:

```
<form class="niceInput" id="PostEditForm" method="post" action="/posts/edit/1" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

After validation errors:

```
<form class="niceInput" id="PostEditForm" method="post" action="/posts/edit" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

What could be causing this?

Thanks

---

EDIT: Added 'edit' method in posts_controller.php

```
    function edit($id) {
    // $id = $this->params['pass'][0];
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Edit post');
    $this->Post->id = $id;  
    $this->Post->user_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');

    $postUserId = $this->Post->read('user_id', $id);

    // check if user logged in owns the post
    if ($this->Auth->user('id') != $postUserId['Post']['user_id']) {
        $this->redirect('/posts/manage');
    }   

    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Post->read();
    } else {
        if ($this->Post->save($this->data)) {

            if (!empty($this->data['Post']['image_files'])){ 
                $this->_moveImages($this->data);
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated.');
            $this->redirect('/posts/manage');
        }
    }
    $this->render('add');
```

---

EDIT 2: add.ctp view

```
if ($this->action == 'edit') {
    echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('class' => 'niceInput', 'action' => 'edit'));
} else {
    echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('class' => 'niceInput'));
}


echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
                        'label' => 'Type of post',
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'options' => array(
                            'rent' => 'Rental',
                            'roommate' => 'Roommate',
                            'sublet' => 'Sublet'
                        )));
echo $this->Form->input('street_address', array('label' => 'Street address'));
echo $this->Form->input('city');
echo $this->Form->input('province');
echo $this->Form->input('price');
echo $this->Form->input('bedrooms');
echo $this->Form->input('bathrooms');
echo $this->Form->input('utilities', array('label' => 'Utilities Included'));
echo $this->Form->input('washer_dryer');
echo $this->Form->input('dishwasher');
echo $this->Form->input('a_c');
echo $this->Form->input('parking_spots');


echo $this->Form->hidden('image_files');
echo $this->Form->input('description');

if ($this->action == 'edit') {
    $buttonLabel = 'Save changes';
} else {
    $buttonLabel = 'Add house';
}

echo $this->Form->button($buttonLabel, array('id' => 'addButton'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Comment: Can you post your `edit` method code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the form helper and explicitly set the url the form points to.

```
<?php echo $form->create('Post', array('url' => $html->url(array('controller'=>'posts', 'action'=>'edit', $this->data['Post']['id'])))); ?>
```

Comment: I did this and it works.. but shouldn't cake be doing this automagically?

Comment: That's 1.2 syntax; if you're using 1.3, it should be `$this->Form->Create('Model')` but otherwise correct. And yes, Cake *should* do this automagically (just the model name), what do you have in your edit view?

Comment: I render the add view, that has a conditional $this->Form->create('Post'). If the action is edit, it includes the 'action' => 'edit parameter. Else, it will only echo $this->Form->create('Post')